# Can I use JavaScript in the description of a WooCommerce product?

Tags: javascript, html, woocommerce

I'm trying to inject a countdown timer into my WooCommerce product, replacing the description. I've got the injection working how I want, but I can't seem to get any output from the script I have. Here's what I'm trying:

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? The description just shows up empty. Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine. I updated to use a snippet, press run snippet. No issue.